# How to get static image paths working in Webpack 2 / React App on localhost?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, localhost, webpack-2

#### Expected

Images and CSS path load up fine locally with no errors

#### Results

404 errors on style and images

[image]

My styles work fine, yet there is a missing error, also the app cannot find the `static/imgs` folder

[image]

My folder structure

[image]

#### Login component

The image path:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="app-bg">
            <section id="auth-section">
                <header>
                    <img src="static/imgs/logo.png"/>
                    <h1>Login to the Manage app</h1>
                </header>
```

#### Webpack Config

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");
const dist = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist");

module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
  entry: [
    "./index.js"
  ],
  output: {
    path: dist,
    filename: "manage2.bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallbackLoader: "style-loader",
          loader: ["css-loader", "sass-loader"],
          publicPath: dist
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    hot: false,
    quiet: true,
    publicPath: "",
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    compress: true,
    stats: "errors-only",
    open: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      // title: "Manage 2.0",
      // hash: true,
      template: "index.html"
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: "manage2.css",
      disable: false,
      allChunks: true
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: "static" }])
  ]
};
```

#### src/index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'
import css from './manage2.scss'
const element = document.getElementById('manage2');
ReactDOM.render(<App />, element);
```

I've tried changing the `publicPath: "/"` to `""`, `./` to no avail...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I needed to change the **publicPath** to below:

```
output: {
  path: dist,
  filename: "manage2.bundle.js",
  publicPath: '/static/',
},
```